# How to disable bounding box padding in NMAMapView (HEREMaps)?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I'm trying to pass the bounding box of one NMAMapView to another NMAMapView but the result is not the same. For testing purpose I've tried:

```
mapView.set(boundingBox: mapView.boundingBox!, animation: .none)
```

After this call the map always zooms a little bit out.
Other SDKs have an edgePadding which could be set to zero. Is this also possible in here-maps for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing view state via `NMAGeoBoundingBox` you can try using passing `geoCenter` and `zoomLevel` via `setGeoCenter:zoomLevel:` and see if this works better for your use case. Alternatively, you could heuristicly reduce the `zoomLevel` after calling `setBoundingBox`. There is no edge padding concept.

Comment: Setting a zoom level after setting a geobounding is causing a default map location loading, Do you know why?